# Methods to increase the speed of dissolving potassium sulfate in water apart from heating, grinding or shaking

Tags: solubility, solutions

I bought potassium sulfate to be used as a fertilizer. The fertilizer comes in the form of small pebbles 1-2mm in diameter. Wikipedia states that the solubility is around 111g/liter at 20°C.

I tested several concentrations

100g / liter

50g  / liter

25g  / liter

at room temperature (22° C). After 2 hours there are still solids remaining in the solution. The water here is hard (EC= 0.6ms / cm) which hinders the dissolution. What can I do to improve the solubility of this fertilizer in water apart from heating, using reverse osmosis, grinding the pebbles or vigorous shaking of the solution (which worked) but is very tedious.

Comment: Did you buy chemically pure (lab grade) potassium sulfate to use as a fertilizer, or did you buy it as fertilizer in the first place? A fertilizer often contains additives such as phosphates that may be less soluble in water. Also, have you tried to warm up the solution?

Comment: The label says potassium sulfate. (K2SO4) I'm using it to blend my fertilizer. It's definitely not lab grade. Warming up the solution will probably work but is impractical as I want to dissolve a large amount.

Comment: I would try to warm up a little portion to see whether the residue is soluble at all and it's not some stone dust. Also, it might help if you add a photo of the label: there might be some useful information regarding the composition of the fertilizer.

Comment: Shaking does not increase the solubility, it merely speeds up the process of dissolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're really asking about *speeding* dissolution, not increasing solubility, use a mixer; either:

- From above, e.g., [a drill attachment for mixing paint](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000I1CEUK), or
- From below, e.g., [a magnetic mixer/stirrer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J59QVGQ).

The links are just as examples; you could devise your own mixer.

Comment: An ultrasound probe would help too, but would be expensive

Comment: Actually, inexpensive ultrasonic humidifiers *might* help, except the beam is focused to a pinpoint. Would it be powerful enough to help if diffused?